# Set column with different time zones as index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with time values from different timezones. See here:

[image]

The start of the data is the usual time and the second half is daylight savings time. As you can see I want to convert it to a datetime column but because of the different time zones it doesn't work. My goal is to set this column as index. How can I do that?

Comment: [Would setting `utc=True` be sufficient](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#to-datetime-tz-examples)?

Comment: Please update your question with code (and text) input/outputs, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[*"... timezone-aware inputs with mixed time offsets ..."*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#to-datetime-tz-examples) can be a bit problematic with Pandas.  However, there is a [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) parameter setting that may be acceptable to use timezone-aware inputs with mixed time offsets as a [`DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html).

Excerpt from [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#to-datetime-tz-examples):

> - ... timezone-aware inputs with mixed time offsets (for example issued from a timezone with daylight savings, such as Europe/Paris)
>   are not successfully converted to a `DatetimeIndex`. Instead a simple
>   `Index` containing `datetime.datetime` objects is returned:
>
> ...
>
> Setting `utc=True` solves most of the ... issues:
>
> ...
>
> - Timezone-aware inputs are converted to UTC (the output represents the exact same datetime, but viewed from the UTC time offset +00:00)
>   [and a `DatetimeIndex` is returned].